# OpenStack: Could not delete Security Group because it says it is in use

Tags: openstack, openstack-neutron

When I'm trying to delete a security group, the delete operation fails

```
neutron security-group-delete f54609e7-f3a3-4b44-8060-2675058ea786
Security Group f54609e7-f3a3-4b44-8060-2675058ea786 in use.
```

I tried to delete all security group rules and the same error message appears.

How can I release it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The security group in matter was attached to a nova server. 
This server also had attached to it a cinder volume.
This volume remained stuck in "Creating" status.

Because of this volume, the security group could not be deleted.

I've identified the problem by using

```
heat event-list <NAME or ID>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have face the same issue and get solved by deleting the ports used in concered security group.

1. `neutron port-list` - (Get all port list and find out concered sec group)
2. `neutron port-delete 6a63e526-164b-4e95-9a7f-ffb05c7c718b` (Delete the concered port)

After clening up ports , Try to delete the concered sec group.

Comment: Just a tip, use `neutron port-list -c id -c security_groups |grep ${security-group-id}` to get all ports that are using a specific sec group.

Answer (score 0):

I have same issue, however we are using nova, I found out that security group was used on one forgotten server, then I deleted it from this server with nova:

```
nova list-secgroup {server_name}
nova remove-secgroup {server_name} {sec_group_id}
```

afterwards

```
openstack security group delete {sec_group_id}
```

was working

Answer (score 0):

My approach to find the offending VM was

```
for serverid in `openstack server list -f value -c ID` ; do
   nova list-secgroup $serverid | grep $SECGROUP && echo $serverid ;
done
```

and then drop it with `nova delete $serverid`